# Aggregating fine resolution raster to coarser resolution such that pixel value of coarse pixel is proportion of unique pixel value in fine res raster

Tags: r, gis, terra

I have a raster with pixel values 1 or NA (first image below) with specifications includedr after image. I want to coarsen to 10km*10km resolution such that the new pixel value in the final coarse pixel is proportion of pixels with value=1 (last image below).

[image]

```
raster1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 33301, 32538, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : 7590450, 10844250, 902100, 4232200  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
source      : spat_PDvNPPxCooNIh09_2584.tif 
name        : pred 
min value   :    1 
max value   :    1
```

How would I do this in R? I primarily use terra R package. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=2, ncol=2, vals=c(NA, 1, 1,NA))
```

Solution

```
a <- aggregate(x, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Illustration

```
values(a)
#     lyr.1
#[1,]   0.5
```

Comment: And if someone is here looking for proportion of pixels in multiclass raster (e.g. raster of terrain types), you need to first `segregate(..., other=NA)`. This will separate your multiclass raster into the stack one class in each layer and then you use this advice to aggregate the whole stack.